# All admin Accounts are blocked

Tags: admin

All our admin accounts are blocked accidentally. I have access to remote server as root. How do I reactivate the accounts

Comment: Hi Ravi, It might help you get helpful answers if you provide more explanation, such as what CMS is it, are the 'blocked' admins also blocked from doing 'admin' stuff in the CMS or only in CRM. etc

Answer (score 1):

Accounts are handled by the CMS, so it depends if you are using drupal, wordpress or Joomla.

Check the documentation of your CMS on you to enable then again, and you should be able to access your site again